# Is it possible to make a python script export itself into a file

Tags: python

I'm learning Python, just for fun really
I was wondering if there is something you can use to make the python script export itself into a file.

Comment: ...like, you want to make a second copy of the script by running it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thiknk that is your answer

```
# example.py

f = open("test.txt", "a")
f.write("Hello!")
f.close()
```

You can write what you want instead of "Hello!"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

```
with open(__file__ + '_copy.py', "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(open(__file__, 'r', encoding='utf-8').read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
a = open("test.py", "r")  # Read the file test.py

b = open("testt.py", "w")  # Write in the file testt.py

b.write(a.read())  # Write in testt.py what is in test.py
```